# Notification icon (count) on jquery mobile footer

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

Is there a css class in jquery mobile which allows notification counts on the footer navbar like this "2" on the picture below?

[image: Example for notification count]

Answer (score 1):

Then you are looking for the Bartender: http://www.stokkers.mobi/valuables/bartender.html

Code can be found here: https://github.com/frequent/bartender/